# How is Inotifyd different from inotifywait in term of monitoring a directory and do some post actions?

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux, inotify

I need to monitor a directory and do some post actions based on the events happened. I am familiar with `inotifywait` but since we use docker based on alpine, I was thinking about is there other way to do that.

Then I found [`Inotifyd`](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Inotifyd), according to the document there said "While there are tools designed around inotify (inotify-tools) alpine has a build in tool called inotifyd (part of busybox) to execute a command on file system events."

But the problem are, a) according that alpine document setting `inotifyd` to work seems quite complicated compared to `inotifywait`  b) I can't find many articles about inotifyd. So I get the feeling that it is not widely-used.

So can someone with experience of Inotifyd shed some light on this ?

Comment: The question you are making is not clear. What do you want actually know?

Comment: A practical example of using inotifyd, and if the example can use inotifywait as well to do the comparison, it will be better.

Comment: A pratical example of using inotifyd is in the URL you have mentioned: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Inotifyd 
Again, your request is vague. Please be more precise if you want a precise answer.
"Comparison" is a big word, what kind of comparison are you looking for? Speed? Memory consumption? Reliability?

Answer (score -1):

I know too not answer well documentation.
Specifically with regard to the highly prized mask.

This may help:

### inotifyd example in a session

```
localhost:~$ cat >handler.sh    
#! /bin/sh  
#1 is event, 2 is file or dir,   
#3 is file only if 2 is dir.   
echo $1 $2 $3  

localhost:~$ inotifyd handler.sh 
test:we &  
[2] 5375  

localhost:~$ touch test  
e       test

localhost:~$ echo "hello" > test  
w       test
```

The mask is optional. If nothing is specified all events are watched.
When specified and more than one event is wanted the **multiple events are collated**.
The example above shows that this works.

The main difference with inotifywait is that with inotifyd the handler can not be specified as an expression. It
is always a seperate file as a PROG. Conversely with inotifywait no handler PROG is specified and instead the inotifywait call output is piped or redirected to a handler EXPRESSION which if desired can call a handler PROG as in these examples:

### inotifywait examples (no session. try them yourself)

```
#pipe inotifywait output  
#(most straight forward)  
#use EXPRESSION    
inotifywait -e modify,attrib -m 
test | while read -r event ; do 
echo $event  ; done &  

#redirect inotifywait output with  
#process substitution.  
#use EXPRESSION  
while IFS= read -r event ; do echo 
$event ; done < <(inotifywait -e 
modify,attrib -m setup) &  

#using a PROG
inotifywait -e modify,attrib -m 
test | while read -r event ; do 
handler.sh ; done &
```

Also with inotifywait you specify if you want to continously monitor the target or not thus allowing one shot
calls:

```
#notice no -m option
inotifywait -e attrib 
crashflagfile | while read -r 
event do ; restart.sh ; done &
```

As for efficiency consider the simple argument processing of -e modify,attrib vs :we
Not only are errors encountered much sooner with :we but the short notation benefits from direct index matching
during the parse on a per char basis across the entire event mask args. This will make for much faster event mask parsing and thus better startup performance for your watches.

For adding watches and dispatching there are differences also. Inotifyd will do an inotify add watch, poll for events and call the handler using an exec or execv call.
inotifywait on the other hand will do an inotify add watch, poll for events and then output (write) the event data whereby the shell will "pipe" the event data to the expression. So it's the exec call VS the write to shell expression. Pretty close race. Even with the ability of inotifyd to use binary executables as handlers a shell expression can hold it's own. Old debate there.

So overall there is some added flexibility with inotifywait, the watch set call contains the handler and so no extra handler file which some prefer whereas others may like the clear seperation of inotifyd and the choice to use executables more directly.
At a quick glance they seem equal in runtime performance but inotifywait
will have slower slartup times (though
this can be fixed by modifying inotifywait's source code to use single chars for the events).
Both are good choices when you don't have to use the inotify library directly.

Have fun monitoring your files!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your comment is vague. Please ellaborate on how exactly the answer is unclear and supposedy doees not answer the question.